# django text field with options

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Hello **I want to know** if it possible to make a text field with options like here in `django`
[image: the options up top]

the options up top to enter image and edit the text and **how**

can I do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the editor plugins for django, examples:

1. [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/) - Django admin CKEditor integration.
2. [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/) - Summernote is a simple WYSIWYG editor. django-summernote allows you to embed Summernote into Django very handy. Support admin mixins and widgets.
3. [django-tinymce](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/) - TinyMCE integration for Django.
4. [django-redactoreditor](https://github.com/mazelife/django-redactoreditor/) - This package helps integrate the Redactor Javascript WYSIWYG-editor in Django.
5. [django-wysiwyg](https://github.com/pydanny-archive/django-wysiwyg/) - A Django application for making Django textareas rich text editors. Certainly as a template tag and possibly as a form widget.
6. [django-markdownx](https://github.com/adi-/django-markdownx) - Comprehensive Markdown plugin built for Django.
7. [django-markdown-editor](https://github.com/agusmakmun/django-markdown-editor) - Django Markdown Editor, supported for Bootstrap & Semantic-UI.

> for more packages: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/wysiwyg/